# How to create dynamically multiple graphql endpoints on expressjs - nodejs

Tags: express, graphql

I'm creating an API where I want to create dynamically multiple graphql endpoints according to the user's preferences without restarting the server.

In general is something very simple, the user will specify the graphql schema and the resolvers, and after the user will push a button to generate a graphql endpoint which will be under the mydomain/randomString

The only code that I can provide so far is how am I creating a graphql endpoint in my expressjs app, which happens on one of the initial files that run when the nodejs server starts.

```
const {ApolloServer, gql} = require('apollo-server-express');
const typeDefs = gql(fs.readFileSync('./server/graphql/schema.graphql', {encoding: 'utf-8'}));
const resolvers = require ('./server/graphql/resolvers');

const graphqlServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs
  ,resolvers
  ,engine: {
    apiKey: "aRandomString"
  }
  ,introspection: true
  // ,context: ({req}) => ({user: req.user && db.users.get(req.user.sub)})
});
```

After the user generates the endpoint, he/she will be able to query on that graphql endpoint.

Comment: simple, sure, make it with severless and provide answer, we'll wait, looks interesting

Comment: Unfortunately, i do not know what is serverless and i do not have enough time these days to implement it with serverless, so my implementation of graphql with serverless will take a while. Thank you!